# ionic 1, I lost my app's icons and splashscreen

Tags: ionic-framework

I am running my app on my phone this morning with

```
ionic run android -lcs
```

as usual. But this morning the icon and splashscreen switched to default images.

How can I get back to normal?

```
$ ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v7.4.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

[image]

Comment: Is your app icons and splash screen images  available inside platform res folder(For e.g. platforms / android / res  folder)?

Comment: no they are not, this directory has the defaut cordova icon

Answer (score 2):

Try to force update the android platform to version 6.1.0:

```
cordova platform update android@6.1.0
```

The current version (6.0.0) has a bug that causes this problem.

EDIT:

Cordova 6.5.0 has been released recently. This release updates cordova-android to version 6.1.1. So best solution now is:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Comment: I just updated to android@6.1.0 as you suggested, I saw the right icon once on my device desktop, I did `ionic platform rm android && ionic platform add android`and now the icon is back to crodova default. And it seems that none of my cordova/ionic plugins are working correctly...particularly, it seems that my app, when running on my device with `ionic run android -lcs` can't seem to be able to connect on the web (ajax request are not working properly)

Comment: I get this type of errors : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Comment: Hi, I did what you suggested, but it keeps coming back to version 6.0.0... Is there anything I should do to keep it to 6.1.0 ?

Comment: Do you remove and add the platform each time you run your app?

Comment: I don't think so. I rm and add the android platform again, I change the version in the package.json. But I don't why, when I run the app on my phone, then it goes back to 6.0.0 !... and the icon is still wrong.

Comment: Just don't rm and add the platform again, but update the platform and directly after that run the app on your phone. Does that work?

Comment: Just to be sure, I just did:
`npm update -g cordova ionic cordova-android && cordova platform update android@6.1.0 && ionic run android -lcs`
and I get a HUGE amount of errors in the console, and the first one is:
AdMobPlugin.java:37: error: package com.rjfun.cordova.ad does not exist
import com.rjfun.cordova.ad.GenericAdPlugin;

Comment: I just tried to remove and install all the plugins, with `ionic plugin rm ...` and then `ionic plugin add ...` but I still have the same errors

Comment: Does this help you: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob/issues/208

Comment: Two days ago Cordova 6.5.0 has been released which includes cordova-android version 6.1.1. Hopefully this helps. I edited the answer with this.

Comment: thanks @JanP, I just re-installed cordova, but when I check the version of android I get this : `$ cordova platform version androidInstalled platforms:
  android 6.1.0
`